# Can you use would when referring to a single event in the past?

Tags: tense

This construction with would is just rubbing me the wrong way, but I'm not sure whether I'm right.

> The majority of their tanks lacked radios, and and often relied on visual confirmation for communication. These deficiencies would again impact French efforts to organize and react to situations quickly when Germany would invade in May of 1940.

Specifically, it's the "when Germany would invade" that bothers me, as this is referring to a single event rather than a recurring one. I'd be more comfortable with a past tense -- "when Germany invaded" -- or just rewriting it entirely, e.g., "following the German invasion."

Answer (score 1):

That's an example of "future in the past", described here:
[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/future-in-the-past)
"When we talk about the past, we sometimes want to refer to something which was in the future at the time we were speaking (about). We use past verb forms to do this:
*They rang to say they **would be** with us by ten o’clock but then their flight was cancelled.* (past form of They will be with us)."

(The word "about" was inserted above by me, as it seems to have been omitted in the definition.)

As you note, simple past would have served there, but this is the perspective that was chosen by the author.

Here is a discussion of another case where simple past would serve but the author chose "future in the past" :
[ELU Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254336/a-question-about-a-sort-of-future-in-the-past-usage)
"In the fifth inning, Smith would homer and Jones would follow with a triple."
The accepted answer points out that the example "could easily be reworded to just use normal past tense".

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I'll accept the argument and bow to experience.